# Load html and css file in build file

Tags: javascript, html, import, fetch, web-component

USE case: Load a static template.html and styles.css dynamically at runtime from index.js. I am able to do it locally. But when build file is run, it throws error that it could find the html file.

I have one html file(template.html) as below

```
<template id="frame">
    <div class="outerwrap h-screen ">
        <header class="bg-deep-ocean-140">
            <div class="flex flex-row items-center min-h-4-5">
                <div class="px-4 grow">
                    <div data-slot="SomeComponentSlot"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="px-4">
                    <div data-slot="LogoutButton"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <main class="h-full p-4">
            <div data-slot="main">Main Content</div>
        </main>
        <footer class="p-4">
            <div data-slot="footer">Footer</div>
        </footer>
    </div>
</template>
```

A css file(styles.css) which contains css for above classes.

I am importing these files in index.js as following:

```
const TEMPLATE_LOCATION = './src/template.html';
const TEMPLATE_STYLES = './src/styles.css';

async function loadAndCloneViewTemplate() {
  const response = await fetch(TEMPLATE_LOCATION);
  const content = await response.text();
  const container = document.createElement('div');
  container.innerHTML = content;
  const template = findInNodeList(
    container.children,
    (o) => o.nodeName === 'TEMPLATE'
  );
  return template.content.cloneNode(true);
}
async function addStyleForViewTemplate() {
  const link = document.createElement('link');
  link.type = 'text/css';
  link.rel = 'stylesheet';
  link.href = TEMPLATE_STYLES;
  return link;
}
```

Then we simply use this function to append them to dom.

```
const template = await loadAndCloneViewTemplate();
const styles = await addStyleForViewTemplate();
const root = document.querySelector('#root');
root.appendChild(template);
root.appendChild(styles);
```

I am using plain vanilla js. This works locally. But when we run build file for this, I am getting following error:
`GET https://<---->.com/src/template.html net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)`
When I checked build file it did not contain css and html content.

I tried changing the fetch with import with some different path for html file. But nothing worked. I am looking for something very simple which could do the job.

Comment: If you want to load static HTML/CSS you can use the [``<load-file>`` Web Component](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd)

Comment: To answer this question, I think I need to know more about what you mean when you say "build file". Are you running something like a webpack build and trying to use fetch to retrieve files from the file system? Do you have a server running that is serving template.html and styles.css on the build system? I'm not quite understanding what your use case is.